Extracting function parameter types from templated function
Suppose I have a template that expect a function pointer:
template <typename FncPtr>
void f(FncPtr fp)
{
   if constexpr ("is_first_arg_double") { // is something like this possible?
      fp(1.0);
   }
   else if constexpr ("is_first_arg_int") { // is something like this possible?
      fp(25);
   }
   else {
      // ...
   }
}

So my particular question is:
Is it possible to extract the arguments that the type FncPtr expects and act accordingly in the template, as indicated in the code comments above?
For my particular case, I know that it will always only contain one argument, but I'd like to know if it is possible to also do this in a variadic way.
I have not been able to find anything in the reference. Closest I could get was result_of.

Write template<typename R, typename... Args> void f(R (*fp)(Args...)) to deduce argument types. This also limits the argument to be a function pointer instead of accepting all types.

you need 2 "function traits" one for function pointers and one for a callable object ... it is never fun to write function traits.

@PasserBy, how about for member function pointers? Will this work as well?

@SupAl For member functions, the syntax would be template<typename Ret, typename C, typename... Args> voidf(Ret (C::*fp)(Args...)) as shown in this answer. Note that member function pointers are not actually pointers in c++.

@user12002570, what are they then, if not pointers?

@SupAl you shouldn't change the question after getting valid answer(s). Instead please post a new question. This is the reason I rolled back your last edit.

@SupAl I've explained why member function pointers are not actually considered pointers per the c++ standard in Are pointers to non-static member function "formally" not considered pointers. That should make it clear.


if it is possible to also do this in a variadic way.

Yes, it is certainly as shown below:
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> void f(Ret (*fp)(Args...))
{
      if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type, double>)
      {
      }
      else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type, int>)
      {
      }
}  


how about for member function pointers?

For member function pointers you can write:
template<typename Ret, typename C, typename... Args> void f(Ret (C::*fp)(Args...))
{
      if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type, double>)
      {
      }
      else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type, int>)
      {
      }
}


You need 47 more overloads for member function pointers to cover all the combinations of const, volatile, ref-qualifiers, noexcept, etc.

@JanSchultke Yes, I know but this should give the basic idea how to implement them to OP so I showed for one and the same can be done for others by OP as an exercise if they really want it.

@JanSchultke Btw I think the dupe can be improved if not reopened. I mean the main problem OP has is that they don't know how to accept function pointers as parameter/argument. So I think that should be added to the dupe list. See if you can find any related to that.

If you want to support any callable you can leverage std::function to figure out the function type and then extract the first parameter from that typed like
// meta function to extract first parameter type of the std::function object
template<typename R, typename... Args>
auto get_first_param(std::function<R(Args...)>) -> decltype(std::get<0>(std::declval<std::tuple<Args...>>())); 

// alias that leverages the meta function to get the type conveniently
template<typename Fn>
using first_param_t = decltype(get_first_param(std::declval<decltype(std::function{std::declval<Fn>()})>()));

template<typename Fn>
void f(Fn fn) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<first_param_t<Fn>, double>) {
        fn(1.0);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<first_param_t<Fn>, int>) {
        fn(25);
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}

void f1(double d) {
    std::cout << "double: " << d << std::endl;
}

void f2(int i) {
    std::cout << "int: " << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(f1);
    f(f2);
}


Do note that no std::function is actually created, it is just used in the unevaluated context to do the heavy lifting of figuring out the function signature.  Changing the std::get<0> in get_first_param to increasing values will allow you to get the next subsequent parameter if you need traits to get the second, third and so on parameter types.

to have your function accept both a function pointer and a callable (lambda) you could use SFINAE with type traits, the following gets the N argument type.
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N, class = void>
struct FunctionArgTraits
{
};

template <int N, typename R, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraits<R(*)(Ts...), N>
{
    using Argtype = typename std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
};

template <typename T, int N>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper
{
};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N>
{
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...) const, N> : FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N > {};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...)&, N > : FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N > {};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...) const&, N > : FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N > {};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...)&&, N > : FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N > {};

template <int N, typename R, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...) const&&, N > : FunctionArgTraitsHelper<R(T::*)(Ts...), N > {};


template <typename Fs, int N>
struct FunctionArgTraits<Fs, N, std::void_t<decltype(&Fs::operator())>>
{
    using Argtype = typename FunctionArgTraitsHelper<decltype(&Fs::operator()), N>::type;
};

template <typename T, int N>
using Argtype_t = typename FunctionArgTraits<T, N>::Argtype;

template <typename FncPtr>
void f(FncPtr fp)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Argtype_t<FncPtr, 0>, double> == true) { 
        fp(1.0);
        std::cout << "double\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Argtype_t<FncPtr, 0>, int> == true) { 
        fp(25);
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}

int func3(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    f(func3);
    f([](double b) {return b; });
}

the main idea is similar to the other answers for function pointers, the main difference is that std::void_t will be more specialized for callables, and then the repeated FunctionArgTraitsHelper are to account for different qualifiers of this, for example a lambda without mutable is R(T::*)(Ts...) const.
this answer is C++17, i think this could be simplified using concepts, but i am not sure.

One way that will enable you to inspect the type of the first parameter of the function passed by pointer (fp), is to change your template in the following way:

fp will actually be a generic function pointer.
The return value (R) of the passed function, its first parameter (P1) and the rest of its parameters (Args...) will be separate template parameters.

Then you can use type traits to inspect the type of P1.
This is demonstrated below:
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename R, typename P1, typename... Args>
void f(R(*fp)(P1, Args...)) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<P1, double>) {
        fp(1.0);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<P1, int>) {
        fp(25);
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}

void f1(double d) {
    std::cout << "double: " << d << std::endl;
}

void f2(int i) {
    std::cout << "int: " << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(f1);
    f(f2);
}

Output:
double: 1
int: 25

Live demo
